# Devexpress: Clearing bound controls of completely filtered GridControl

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a `Devexpress.XtraGrid.GridControl` that I have set the `DataSource` to a `DataTable`. I also have several other controls that have databindng to the same `DataTable`. This works out well so that when the selected row of the `GridView` changes, the controls reflect the change.

However, on the `GridControl`'s `GridView` I have set the `ActiveFilter.NonColumnFilter`. This filter changes as the form is used. Occasionally, the filter gets set to something that makes no rows show up in the `GridControl`. When this happens, the controls that are bound to the `DataTable` do not clear, but instead show the data from the last selected row.

Is there something simple I can do to tell the bound controls to clear, or do I need to manually go through them all and clear them?

I had previously used a `DataTable` that actually added and removed rows appropriate to what I was filtering. If the table became clear, all of the bound controls did as well. So I'm assuming it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted DevExpress about this issue and received a [response](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q359637.aspx):

> Thank you for your question. When the grid is completely filtered and contains no rows, it cannot set the current item in the binding source.
>
> To solve this problem I suggest you filter data on the datasource level.

Using this information, I changed from using the `GridView.ActiveFilter.NonColumnFilter` for my filtering needs and instead used the `DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter`. That appears to have solved my issue.

This was different from the example they gave me:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
DataView dv = new DataView();

DataTable dt = CreateTable(10);
dv = new DataView(dt);
bs.DataSource = dv;

gridControl1.DataSource = bs;
textEdit1.DataBindings.Add("EditValue",bs,"Name");
textEdit2.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", bs, "ID");
```

You can then call this to set the filter:

```
   dv.RowFilter = "ID = 50";
```